# How to convert a MAP into a LIST in DART?

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart

i'm having trouble to convert a MAP into a LIST on DART.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
try {
      var response = await http.get(url, headers: header);

      List listaResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);

      final lockers = <Locker>[];

      for (Map map in listaResponse) {
        Locker l = Locker.fromJson(map);
        lockers.add(l);
      }
      return lockers;
    } catch (e) {
      print("error in api ");
      print(e);
    }
```

This is the output error:

```
I/flutter (14625): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'
```

And this is how my json looks like:

```
{
meus_testes_vw: [
    {
    id_teste = 73,
    otherinfo = ahsuasa 
    ........
    },
    {
    id_teste = 74, 
    ........
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON Data is not a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` but a `Map<String, List<Map<String, dynamic>>>`: `{ 'meus_testes_vw': [...] }`.

Try to change the assignment of your `listaResponse`:

```dart
List listaResponse = jsonDecode(response.body)['meus_testes_vw'];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Really thank you very much !!!!! Solved it. I had this problem for two days